# Excel document open by two users. Update the data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an Excel document that is used by two users. Each inputs different data to the same document (two open instances of the same document).

Can I update the data via VBA if I press a button? So the two open instances of the document are synced.

This file is stored on a SharedPoint server.

Answer (score 4):

You can set an Excel workbook to be shared without needing any VBA or other tools.

1. Go to the `Review` tab, click `Share Workbook`
2. In the `Editing` tab, click `Allow changes by more than one user at the same time. This also allows workbook merging`. Choose any `Advanced` options that apply to your situation.
3. Upon clicking `Ok` you should be prompted to save the document. Other users can now make amendments simultaneously, and any conflict issues will prompt the user for action.

More information on this can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-a-shared-workbook-to-collaborate-b8207fe9-a613-483f-b804-0ca4658b0c61).

Note that if you are using SharePoint, you can use [the web app](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/01/21/collaborative-editing-using-excel-web-app.aspx) to collaborate also.